# App Engine Datastore storing email in wrong format

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

My app receives incoming email and saves the sender's email address into the datastore. Problem is it saves them in this format:

`John Smith <jsmith@email.com>`

Because of the way my app and it's queries are set up I can only search for addresses in this format: `jsmith@email.com`

I have tried to use regex to format the messages but it doesn't work for some reason, I get list index out of range errors on every expression I try. here is the code for my mail handler if that is helpful.

I have checked the logs in App Engine and incoming messages do come in in the format I need, but then I check the datastore entities and it adds it in with the name as well.

I just need to know how I can get email addresses stored without the extra bits.

```
import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import mail_handlers
from google.appengine.api import mail
import os
from main import WorkRequest
import re


class IncomingMailHandler(mail_handlers.InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        (encoding, payload) = list(message.bodies(content_type='text/plain'))[0]
        body_text = payload.decode()
        logging.info('Received email message from %s, subject "%s": %s' %
                     (message.sender, message.subject, body_text))

        logging.info (message.sender)
        logging.info(message.subject)
        logging.info(body_text)


        sender = str(message.sender)
        logging.info(sender)

        email_address = re.findall('<([^>])>', sender)[0]

        wr = WorkRequest()

        wr.email = email_address
        wr.userId = None
        wr.title = message.subject
        wr.content = body_text
        wr.status = "OPEN"
        wr.submission_type = "EMAIL"
        wr.assigned_to = "UNASSIGNED"
        wr.put()

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_ah/mail/.+', IncomingMailHandler)],debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless something got mangled when your code fragement was posted, that regex is very unlikely to match. Try

```
email_address = re.findall('<(.*?)>', sender)[0]
```

That will handle that one particular form of address.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of regex:

```
email = email.split('<')[1].split('>')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseaddr` function from the standard library's `email` package.

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> sender = 'John Smith <jsmith@email.com>'
>>> name, address = parseaddr(sender)
>>> print name
John Smith
>>> print address
jsmith@email.com
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr):

> Parse address – which should be the value of some address-containing
> field such as To or Cc – into its constituent realname and email
> address parts. Returns a tuple of that information, unless the parse
> fails, in which case a 2-tuple of ('', '') is returned.